# <p:dataTable> dynamically make visible or hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have multiple dataTables in a page , each dataTable is in separate form, i want to show the dataTable only when user wants to see that datatable by selecting the checkbox.Below is the code:

--EDIT--
show.xhtml

```
    <h:form>
  <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{salesMB.selectedItems}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{salesMB.availableItems}" />
          <p:ajax update=":salesForm :workForm" />  
 </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    </h:form>
    <!--dataTable which shows Sales status -->
    <h:form id="salesForm">

     <p:dataTable id="salesID" var="salesInfo" value="#{salesMB.salesInfoList}" widgetVar="widgetSalesInfo"
                resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria">

    <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="Sales Status"/>
     </f:facet>  

    <p:column id="salesport" sortBy="saID" headerText="SalesReport" >  
                <h:outputText value="#{salesInfo.report}" />
            </p:column>
    ....
    ...
    </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>

    <!--dataTable which shows workstatus -->
    <h:form id="workForm">

      <p:dataTable id="orderID" var="orderInfo" value="#{salesMB.orderInfoList}" widgetVar="widgetOrderInfo"
                resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria">

    <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="Work Status"/>
      </f:facet>  

    <p:column id="orderp" sortBy="ordID" headerText="ordReport" >  
                <h:outputText value="#{salesInfo.order}" />
            </p:column>
    ....
    ...
    </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

SalesManagedBean:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "salesMB")
    @ViewScoped
    public class SalesManagedBean implements Serializable {
   private List<String> selectedItems;
        /**
     * @return the selectedItems
     */
    public List<String> getSelectedItems() {
        return selectedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedItems the selectedItems to set
     */
    public void setSelectedItems(List<String> selectedItems) {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }

    ..
    }
```

When i select checkbox with label "Sales Status" , dataTable with header "Sales Status" should be visible to the users , similarly when checkbox with label "Sales Status" is unselected datatable  with header "Sales Status" should be hidden.When i select multiple checkbox, multiple forms mapped should be visible. How can i achive this dynamically, onchange of selectbox dataTable should be hidden or visible.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form>
     <p:selectOneRadio  value="#{salesMB.selectedBox}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Sales Status" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Work Status" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
            <p:ajax update=":salesForm :workStatusForm" />
     </p:selectOneRadio>    
</h:form>
<h:form id="salesForm">
         <!--dataTable which shows Sales status -->
    <p:dataTable id="salesID" rendered="#{salesMB.selectedBox == '1'}" var="salesInfo" value="#{salesMB.salesInfoList}" >
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<h:form id="workStatusForm">
        <!--dataTable which shows workstatus -->
    <p:dataTable id="orderID" rendered="#{salesMB.selectedBox == '2'}" var="orderInfo" value="#{salesMB.orderInfoList}" >
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This one above is how your xhtml file should look like. Keep the managed bean class. I hope it helps.

Comment: i want to have multiple checkbox and onselect of checkboxes the want to show or hide the datatables. I have modified the code in the above post accordingly.I could not able to sho or hide when i select or deselct the checkbox. Please suggest.Thanks.